# Debug on Server side

Tags: axapta, ax

I have a Microsoft dynamics Ax client instance. While posting packing slip on Sales Order I have encountered some errors.

So I started debugging the code but I did not find any solution. I have learned that those methods are being called on server side.

Is there any possibility to debug those methods on Client side?

If not how to find out in general which methods are called during the process. Please provide the answer in general way. These question is not about errors in Sales Order pacing slip.

Apart from Debugging is there any way to find out which methods are called during execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to enable debugging on Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/01/05/how-to-enable-debugging-on-server-dynamics-ax.aspx) and [Debug X++ code in a Batch Server in AX 2009](http://axwonders.blogspot.com/2011/11/debug-x-code-in-batch-server-in-ax-2009.html).

Besides debugging there is [tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axinthefield/archive/2010/12/28/dynamics-ax-tracing-part-1.aspx).

Comment: Updated link for Cesar's blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/how-to-enable-debugging-on-server-dynamics-ax/