# Transactions in a Purchase Order (type order: Return Order)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

When I make a purchase order (Type: purchase order), and I post a packing slip, Ax generates transactions like this:

```
Account:  253   debit:100   (packing slip account)
Account: 6133   credit:100  (packing slip offsetaccount)
```

When I post the Invoice, it generates these transactions:

```
Account: 6033    debit:100  (inventory account)
Account: 40111   debit:18   (Tax)<br>
Account: 4212    credit:118 (providers)
```

But when I make a purchase order type "returned order" because I'm going to make a return to the provider.

I post a packing slip, and Ax generates transactions like this:

```
Account: 253  credit:100  (packing slip account (TPS))
Account: 6133 debit:100   (packing slip offsetaccount (TPS))
```

When I post the Invoice generate this transactions:

```
Account: 253    debit:  100   (packing slip account) (Invert of TPS)
Account: 6133   credit: 100   (packing slip offsetaccount) (Invert of TPS)
Account: 6033   credit: 100  (inventory account)
Account: 40111  credit:  18   (Tax)
Account: 4212   debit:  118   (providers)
```

When I create a purchase order of type "returned order," why does Ax generate these 2 transactions (Invert of TPS) when I post the invoice?.

Is possible to not generate these two transactions?

Comment: If i turn off packing slip posting, Ax do not register the transactions of packing slip, I just need to Ax the following transactions will not generate when  I make a purchase order type "returned order" and i post the invioce:

Account: 253    debit:  100   (packing slip account) (Invert of TPS)
Account: 6133   credit: 100   (packing slip offsetaccount) (Invert of TPS)
 
The other transactions of packing slip be generated.

Comment: If I packing slip post purchase order (Type:purchase order), generates:Account:253 debit:100, Account:6133 credit:100, when i make a purchase order type "returned order" and i packing slip post generates:Account:253 credit:100,Account:6133 debit:100, these last two transactions reversed the first two transactions, until that point all correct, but when I post the invoice of a purchase order type "returned order" generate these: Account:253 debit:100, Account:6133 credit:100,These transactions invert the generated in the previous step, Is possible to not generate these two transactions?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the problem with two transactions.

When you make a purchase order the first two transactions debit and credit the two accounts 253 and 6133, respectively.
When you make the return order the first two transactions must be inverted, i.e. there are (inverse) transactions with credit and debit on the same two accounts 253 and 6133, respectively.

If these inverse transactions are not created then the Ledger accounts will be wrong.

And to answer you question: Yes, you can override the standard posting mechanisms in code. But you shouldn't do that in this case.

Comment: If I packing slip post purchase order (Type:purchase order), generates:Account:253 debit:100, Account:6133 credit:100, when i make a purchase order type "returned order" and i packing slip post generates:Account:253 credit:100,Account:6133 debit:100, these last two transactions reversed the first two transactions, until that point all correct, but when I post the invoice of a purchase order type "returned order" generate these: Account:253 debit:100, Account:6133 credit:100,These transactions invert the generated in the previous step, Is possible to not generate these two transactions?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an application error.

Why do people make errors? Because they are human.

Cause? Try to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888533/debug-on-server-side).

It is possible to turn off packing slip posting, see Accounts Payable\Setup\Parameters,  tab page Update, field "Post packing slip in ledger".

Comment: If i turn off packing slip posting, Ax do not register the transactions of packing slip, I just need to Ax the following transactions will not generate when  I make a purchase order type "returned order" and i post the invioce:

Account: 253    debit:  100   (packing slip account) (Invert of TPS)
Account: 6133   credit: 100   (packing slip offsetaccount) (Invert of TPS)
 
The other transactions of packing slip be generated.

Comment: Then you will have to change the logic of the "returned order" posting. Whether you use debugging or code reading to analyze the logic is up to you.